Sending a SIGINT to specific thread with pthread_kill() results in whole process termination
I have a very big multithreaded C appication (for this and some other reasons I can not provide the entire code). Long story short, among others there are two threads: thread 1 sends SIGINT to thread 2 while thread 2 waits in ppoll(). Code looks something like that:
Thread 1:
...

if (thread && pthread_kill(&thread, SIGINT) != 0)
{
    fprintf(log1, "Got error: %s", strerror((int)errno));
}

...

thread here is pthread_t variable containing handle of thread 2.
Thread 2:
...
sigset_t mask;
int rc;

sigemptyset(mask);

...

while(true)
{
    ...
    rc = ppoll(fds, nfds, NULL, mask);
    if (rc < 0)
    {
        if (errno == EINTR) fprintf(log2, "Got EINTR");
        else fprintf(log2, "Got error: %s", strerror((int)errno));
        continue;
    }

    fprintf(log, "%d descriptor(s) ready", rc);
}

...

When thread 1 calls pthread_kill it is expected from thread 2 to drop from ppoll() and print "Got EINTR" to log, but for some reason the entire process gets terminated.
Other things I currently know:

The code worked as expected in the past. Since then some seemingly unrelated changes were made to allow the application to load data from Postgres database rather than Oracle (old implementation used Pro*C, new uses libpq). Nothing was altered in the source code of functions responsible for working with threads.

I checked which threads creates which, what signals are being sent (from/to) and in what order does all of this happen. But all that looked identical between old and new versions (besides that the new version stops working the moment thread 1 sends SIGINT to thread 2 and the old version continues working with thread 2 successfully printing "Got EINTR" to log.


2.5 I am absolutely sure that thread 1 sends SIGINT signal after thread 2 reashes ppoll().

I tried using gdb and with great effort was able to once again confirm that the correct thread receives SIGINT but sadly nothing more.

I tried creating a minimum reproducible example but failed to come up with one yet (everything works as expected)


I have very little experience with signals (and even less experience with using them in multithreaded applications but it is what it is) so I likely did not provide enough information but I'm not expecting the exact answer - just some ideas of how to know what could be causing this issue. I will update the question with more specific info if pointed out in comments.

Threads and signals doesn't really match. Some signal can be thread-specific, some can not. And for those that are not thread-specific, then IIRC the system could deliver the signal to any thread which doesn't mask it.

@some-programmer-dude I know but unfortunately the code is already written like that. Also it does not explain why the older version works without any issues.

Is there some code for setting up the signal disposition and/or signal mask?

The only place signal masks are being manipulated in any way is thread 2: a signal mask variable mask is created, then initialized with sigemptyset() call, then passed to ppoll().

Print the SIGINT disposition right before ppoll in both versions.  I suspect you'll see that Pro*C rudely installed its own SIGINT handler whereas libpq leaves you with SIG_DFL.  In the latter case, then, your process suffers the default disposition of SIGINT, which is abnormal termination.

Thanks for the suggestion, I will give it a try. In the meantime I was able to compare signal masks of threads created with old and new versions and they differ in SigIgn and SigCgt so this might also be part of the picture.

@pilcrow you were right, that was exactly the problem. For my setup it was enough to install a dummy handler for signal SIGINT in thread 2. Please post the answer so I could accept it.

@Kekers_Dev, posted. Thanks!

(@Kekers_Dev, this might not be necessary, but just to clarify, signal disposition is process-wide, not thread-specific.  So it doesn't matter if you install your dummy handler in thread 2 or thread 1 or main before any other thread is spawned.)

The old Pro*C library rudely installs signal handlers, including, presumably, one for SIGINT.  libpq does not.
Thus, when the SIGINT is delivered during ppoll, the Oracle-aware version of the code runs its SIGINT action and carries on.  The Postgres-aware version does not, leaving you with SIG_DFL process termination.
As you discovered, installing a dummy or noop handler for SIGINT fixes the problem.

I think you are simply missing a signal handler.
Signal dispositions work on a per-process basis. The default signal disposition for SIGINT is to terminate the current process. This means that if you haven't registered a signal handler (or you are ignoring the signal altogether) the default signal disposition will determine what happens. For SIGINT, the default is to terminate the process (and therefore all its threads).
If you have at least one thread that has not blocked the signal, you did not ignore the signal and you did not register any handler for the signal, your process will be terminated. Note that "ignored" signals and "blocked" signals are two different things.
If you want to be able to catch the signal at all during ppoll, you will have to register an handler for it and also make sure that it's not in the mask you pass.

When thread 1 calls pthread_kill it is expected from thread 2 to drop from ppoll() and print "Got EINTR" to log, but for some reason the entire process gets terminated.

This is only expected if you have a signal handler registered. If not, your whole process will be terminated as it should, because of the default disposition for SIGINT.

My suggestion: take a good read of man 7 signal, this will clear some doubts you may have and help you understand better how signals work.

Rather than using signals (which are somewhat fragile in a multithreaded environment because they involve a lot of whole-process state), you may find a more reliable alternative to interrupt that ppoll() call is to create a pipe using pipe(2), add the read side file descriptor into the polling set, and write a single byte to the write side when you want to interrupt the poll.

Thanks, I will consider that as a future refactoring option
